# How do obtain a descending list of groups of a column that is the sum of another of that group's column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to understand how to order descending a group of column values based on the sum of another column from that group.

From the sample data:

```
mtype    location    mcount
===========================
X        TX          4
Z        AL          10
C        TX          15
M        AL          3
Z        TX          12
M        CT          4
M        TX          20
Z        CT          40
```

First I want to determine the SUM(mcount) by state.

```
location    SUM(mcount)
=======================
TX          51
CT          44
AL          13
```

Then based on that SUM i'd like to have the state rows with the highest SUM returned first then so on and so on.

so the above data would be returned like this (all TX rows first, then CT, then AL last)

```
mtype    location    mcount
===========================
X        TX          4
C        TX          15
Z        TX          12
M        TX          20
M        CT          4
Z        CT          40
Z        AL          10    
M        AL          3
```

The order of rows beyond the sum the group sum of their counts doesn't matter.

I have gotten as far as obtaining the list of states with the highest total mcount descending:

```
SELECT [LOCATION]
FROM A_TABLE
GROUP BY [STATE]
ORDER BY SUM(MCOUNT) DESC
```

To get my final return table should throw that into a temp table and iterate through the [STATE] values?
Something like

```
For each [LOCATION] in temptable
    SELECT * FROM temptable tt WHERE tt.LOCATION = [LOCATION]
Next
```

Then somehow union the results?  What is the suggested way of handling this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a windowed `SUM` in the `ORDER BY`:

```sql
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('X','TX',4),
                ('Z','AL',10),
                ('C','TX',15),
                ('M','AL',3),
                ('Z','TX',12),
                ('M','CT',4),
                ('M','TX',20),
                ('Z','CT',40))V(mtype,location,mcount))
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY SUM(mcount) OVER (PARTITION BY location) DESC,
         mcount;
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  How would you select the top 2 distinct locations from that?  In this case, returning the 6 rows belonging to TX and CT.

Comment: That's a separate question, in my opinion, @CarlosMendieta , however, there are plenty of answers demonstrating this. For example [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841644/2029983). The logic to get the top 2 is identical.